# "Object Variable Not Set" on IXMLDOMNode of MsXml-DOMDocument procedure

Tags: xml, ms-access, xpath, vba

So  I have this pretty large XML file (40MB) that I'll have to repeatedly search.  I've been schooled on the benefits of DOMDocument usage with XPath, and I thought I had it right, but I'm getting the Obj Var Not Set nonsense.

Here's the initial load...I think its loading because it delays an appropriate length of time for a 40mb file & returns no error.

```
Dim someElement As IXMLDOMNode
Dim xmlDoc As Object
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")

'<-thats a valid file name lookup
xmlDoc.Load DLookup("gsgtver", "Eramdat", "EramID = 1")
```

So heres where it gets dicey.   I need a IXMLDOMNode to read the parced xmlDoc object.  I checked the MsXml 6.0 reference library, and I'm getting the var type when I dim (you know, the list of types that fill in for us noobs).
And after I have a IXMLDOMNode set I get the list of methods (like ".text") when I try to assign, but I'm bangin on this error ..... could be a bum xpath string (although I pretty much verbatim stole it from the xpath tutorial).

```
sNodeName = "/Fix_Records/FixRecord/FixID[1]/Latitude"
Set someElement = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(sNodeName)

'yes, I dimmed xBuffer as a string up above
sBuffer = someElement.text
```

Incedently, I REALLY wanna do a "FixID = 'mystring' " sorta thing, but I'm  doing element 1 just to get it workin.
And here's the top of the xml file:

```
<Fix_Records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Fix.xsd"> 
 <!-- ******************************************************** -->
 <!-- Local SITE ID        : ZAB                               -->
 <!-- Local Release Version: a082a210                          -->
 <!-- NASD/NADR Version    : z084b210                          -->
 <!-- Date                 : 02-03-2011 19:02:56               -->
 <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <FixRecord>
      <FixId>00BTR</FixId>
      <IcaoCode>K7</IcaoCode>
      <FixType>WAYPOINT</FixType>
      <FixName>BTR055100</FixName>
      <FixinUs>true</FixinUs>
      <IsNational>true</IsNational>
      <HighPowerVor>false</HighPowerVor>
      <DPositionMapData>false</DPositionMapData>
      <Latitude>31170205N</Latitude>
      <Longitude>089353453W</Longitude>
      <AngularCorr>-0.010472</AngularCorr>
      <XSpherical>0.006082693951808</XSpherical>
      <YSpherical>-0.85612436871425</YSpherical>
      <ZSpherical>0.516734038096893</ZSpherical>
    </FixRecord>
    <FixRecord>
      <FixId>00N10</FixId>
      <IcaoCode>MM</IcaoCode>
```

Thank you.....you smart people rock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a case sensitive problem - you're looking for FixID, you've actually got FixId.
When you try and access its text you throw an exception as you have no actual object.

EDIT: as pointed out by Jean-François Corbett, your XPath is also wrong. Here is an updated Xpath solving both problems:

```
"/Fix_Records/FixRecord[FixId='Id you want']/Latitude"
```

You may also want to test if you've got a node to access, see the answer below for some tips.

Comment: Well....I guess YOU are actually the first winner.  I thought I pasted your line & it didn't work, but its actually the same as JFC's....and I've now read all the comments.  So Thanks, you get the answer.   I hope I did this creditting thing right.

Comment: Well there were two answers that solved half the problem, each updated to fix the rest, it's up to you to choose which answer you prefer, though they're almost identical. I voted up JFCs answer in a spirit of sharing :-)

Comment: Oh and looked at the testing code below, there isn't a check for whether your node is returned in it . the childnode.length test will still be throwing an exception. Try 'if not myNode Is Nothing' (do processing) else (oops, it went wrong).

Comment: Thx James.....Yah, I got a little wrapped around the axle on who answered what first...Tried to be joo-dishes.  And thanks for the error tip...I was back here hoping that the child node exception would be addressed as I'm havin a tuff time trappin it back in my spagetti.

Comment: It's not really a problem, StackOverflow is generally fairly laid back about that sort of thing. Precedence normally goes to the first correct answer, but a later answer that has more/better detail is also a fair choice. And you can always vote up any answers that were helpful. Good that you're accepting answers though, newer users don't always remember! Have a Miles and Trane weekend, Mr Jazaddict.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath is wrong. `"/Fix_Records/FixRecord/FixID[1]/Latitude"` means you're looking for the `Latitude` child element of the first `FixID` child element of THE `FixRecord` element.

But:

- There are many `FixRecord` elements,
- For any given `FixRecord`, there is only one `FixId` child element (no need to specify `[1]`), and
- Most importantly, `FixId` does not have a `Latitude` child element! So you're looking for something that isn't there, which is what is causing the error.

  - Also watch out for case sensitivity as pointed out by @James Walford. `FixId` not `FixID`

I think that what you want is: `"/Fix_Records/FixRecord[1]/Latitude"`.

When you feel ready to go to the next level, try this:

`"/Fix_Records/FixRecord[FixId='mystring']/Latitude"`.

If that doesn't work, there may be some namespace weirdness... Try adding `xsi:` before each node specification in the Xpath:

```
"/xsi:Fix_Records/xsi:FixRecord[1]/xsi:Latitude"
"/xsi:Fix_Records/xsi:FixRecord[xsi:FixId='mystring']/xsi:Latitude"
```

Keep up the spirits, you'll get there eventually!!

Comment: JFC, you're my hero.  I didn't need the xsi part...got er on the first "paste" of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Once the XML is loaded, there's still a possibility of a parsing error. This code may help you to find where the problem lies. Change it accordingly to fit your environment.

The error numbers (6666) are obviously a joke, you must have proper err numbers for your application.

**Edit:** Also, try parse your XML (or at least part of it) in a XML validator, like http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/.

```
Public Sub readXMLDoc()

    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim lookupNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim vOut As Variant
    Dim sNodeName As String
    Dim sParseError As String


    On Error GoTo ProcError

    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    objXML.async = False
    objXML.LoadXML "c:\XMLSample.xml"

    If objXML Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 6666, , "Error while opening the XML file"

    sParseError = objXML.parseError.reason

    If Len(sParseError) > 0 Then Err.Raise 6666, , "Error while parsing the XML file: " & sParseError

    sNodeName = "/Fix_Records/FixRecord/FixID[1]/Latitude"

    Set lookupNode = objXML.SelectSingleNode(sNodeName)

    If lookupNode.ChildNodes.Length > 0 Then

        'Do your handling

    End If

ProcExit:

    Exit Sub

ProcError:

    Debug.Assert False
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub
```

Comment: THanks all...I'll have to chew on this stuff awhile....and not til Monday prolly.

Comment: Thanks for the tester code...I'll keep it handy for the inevitable "next time" I can't make this work.